# Will an average of neural net weights be as effective as one humungous similation?

Tags: neural-network

I'm planning to write a neural network to predict the closing price on day n, using open, high,low,close,& volume for days n-10 to n-1, and doing this for apx 800 days.

I was going to use an 'all but 1' strategy for validation, but this would basically square the number of simulations I'd have to run. Very inefficient!

Should it be significantly less accurate if I ran the simulation just once for each of the 800 days, and stored the weights, and then, for validation, average the weights for all dates except the one to be predicted and the 10 preceding dates?

If the transfer function were linear, it should make no difference, but of course that logistic function makes it non-linear.